# Tweepy Entities Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, entities, tweepy

I'm working on a twitter client and I'm using tweepy, but with it I can't obtain entities in the user_timeline. How can I get the entities?
Have someone updated the Tweepy for AppEngine Library?

Comment: Saying "I can't do x" isn't very useful unless you tell us _why_ you can't do x. What happens when you try?

Comment: Please note that you are using app engine, which means that you are sharing a public ip with many people. This may cause you to be rate limited for public function which don't require authentication, but rate you based on your ip. But that shouldn't be the case for user_timeline?

Comment: Hey Nick & Sam. I'm getting the same problem. Let me give you some more details: include_entities and include_rts don't work when calling user_timeline in tweepy. They do work when you call home_timeline. All calls are oauth-enabled meaning twitter is not looking at the IP's (running locally anyway). I had to go into the tweepy API class and add the two properties to the allowed properties under user_timeline, I also had to make user_timeline oauth enabled. These are just simple configurations. I checked into the returned JSON from Twitter, and neither the RT's not entities are present.

Answer (score 2):

From the [tweepy wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/wiki/CodeSnippets),

```
# Iterate through the first 200 statuses in the friends timeline
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_timeline).items(200):
    # Process the status here
    process_status(status)
```

Comment: Uhm, I can't understad. I need to store the media urls in the entities from user_timeline. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply `include_entities = True`:

```
api.user_timeline(include_entities = True).
```

The reason this is not set to true on default is because entities was added into the Twitter API later, and consequently it was added to Tweepy later.